# Setup Eclipse on Fedora LiveUSB for Developing C Application

Tags: fedora, eclipse, c

I don't have a lot of disk space on my computer, so I'm thinking of installing a version of Fedora on LiveUSB with an Eclipse package to program and debug C applications for one of my lectures, no other usages, yet.

Only issue is i don't know how to do this. I have installed a version of Fedora to LiveUSB, but not sure on exactly how to install and setup eclipse for usage. Tried it before, but it didn't recognize any of the commands and wouldn't compile.

Does anyone have any useful guides?

Comment: Your question was a little unclear, do you have a working LiveUSB that you can boot from? Or did you perhaps mean `install and setup eclipse for usage`?

Comment: yes, i have already got it installed on LiveUSB and am running it atm. Yeah, it was to properly install and setup eclipse

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm afraid I can't help you with that then :\ I was hoping you were having a problem getting the LiveUSB working, which I could have helped with. I haven't gotten around to installing eclipse on my fedora install yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just download and extract the files and run it. You of course have to have the jre installed along with a few other dependencies.
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Eclipse34